# Get array of text values using selector instead of iterating?

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML like:

```
<ul id='foo'>
    <span><a>hello 1</a></span>
    <span><a>hello 2</a></span>
    <span><a>hello 3</a></span>
</ul>
```

I want to get an array of all the text values of the  elements like:

```
var texts = [ 'hello 1', 'hello 2', 'hello 3' ];
```

I'm trying to iterate over each one, is there some way in jQuery to just grab all of them using a selector?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can do it using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like this:

```
var myArray = $("#foo span a").map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
              }).get();
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ABfRC/).

Comment: I know `.get()` returns a basic array, but what is it doing and why does it do that? Can't seem to find an explanation in the jQuery refs (just a mention that that's what it does).

Comment: @Peter - It's basically calling `.toArray()` to get a clean array back, without the extra jQuery properties.

Answer (score 12):

Or a little bit shorter than the accepted answer:

```
$.map($("#foo span a"), $.text)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('#foo span a').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

Comment: You're missing a close paren at the end ( also, this results in a jQuery-wrapped array, not a basic array ( a `.get()` at the end would give you a basic array) ).

Comment: Yep... it was fixed immediately, but you must've loaded it at just the right time :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
var texts = new Array();

$('#foo > span > a').each(function() 
{ 
  texts.push( $( this ).text() ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, the function to get the array of values with *trimmed spaces*:

```
var array = $('li').map(function(){
               return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get();
```

Comment: This is a very useful addition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var texts = new Array();
//or... var texts = [];

$('#foo a').each(function() {
    texts.push($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: `array()` is PHP. To create an empty array in JavaScript, the array literal `[]` is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

use the jquery selector:

```
$("ul#foo span a")
```

Comment: This is all the `a` tags, not the contents of all the `a` tags.