# Jquery - All li values to an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, list

```
<ul class="list" style="">
    <h2 class="list-heading">text</h4>
    <li class="list-h" style="></li>
    <span class="sp"></span>
```

How do i get the text in span into an array?
*there are 3 more li like that

Comment: what has been tried so far

Comment: the text in span? there is no text in the span

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/map

Comment: var values = [];

$('ul.list li span.sp').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});

Comment: a lot varations of this

Comment: Check out possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496338/4951147

Comment: thanks guys, with map function documentation and similar problem that was posted by dangor got what i wanted pretty easily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made some small fixes on your example code to be processable. (At least syntactically correct)

HTML example

```html
<ul class="list">
    <h2 class="list-heading">text</h2>
    <li class="list-h">
     <span class="sp">text1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-h">
     <span class="sp">text2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-h">
     <span class="sp">text3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Js to collect all `<span>`'s content:

```js
var texts = [];

$(function() {
    $('ul span').each(function(){
        texts.push($(this).text());
    });

    alert(texts);
});
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/dq6k8guy/)

Answer (score -1):

From OP's edit:

```
var myArray = $(".list span.sp").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```